# How to reference equation of type $$ formula $$

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I have the tex file of a paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.00841) in which all equations are written in the following format:
`$$y = a*x+b $$`

Equations aren't declared as \begin{equation} and \end{equation} anywhere. Every equation in the paper has a unique equation number, and as I am making this paper part of a 100-page thesis, I would like to reference the equations directly. When I add `\label{some_label_name}` in front of the `$$ formula $$` equation, it only references the entire, chapter, and not just the individual equation. What can I do, other than manually changing all equations in this and all other papers?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I would say you will have to take the only possible way and to replace all the `$$ ... $$` by `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`. The unique number you're talking about has been added manually by the authors and cannot be referenced

Comment: Please clarify how the "unique equation numbers" are assigned. Via `\tag` instructions, maybe? Are the unique equation numbers visible to readers? Please be specific.

Comment: I might be wrong, but that document looks very (plain) TeX-y to me. Equations use `$$...$$` and are manually labelled with `\eqno`. If you want to use portions of the document in a new LaTeX document, it would be a good idea to modify a few things. You would for example turn `$$H = \pmatrix{ 0 & A^\dagger \cr A & 0 \cr}.  \eqno(1) $$` into `\begin{equation}H = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & A^{\dagger} \\ A & 0 \end{pmatrix}.\end{equation}` and let LaTeX assign the numbers automatically.

Comment: A regex match might be able to replace them all with environments.

Comment: Are you including the paper, perhaps? I don't think so. Just don't take it as a model for writing LaTeX, because it ***isn't*** LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments! Yes, this paper is plain TeX, and I simply copy-pasted it into a LaTeX file. I suppose @KersouMan is right, and I will have to manually do all the replacements everywhere